# Classes in JavaScript ECMAScript 5?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-5

I would like to get to know if there are classes in JavaScript ECMAScript 5? I read some literature and there are different opinions about it. I know that it is possible to emulate classes, but I am not sure if they are called classes. Do you maybe also have some proofs?

Are these classes simply pseudo classes or what is the correct term for it?

Comment: When you use `class` in ES2015 (ES6), you're not doing anything you can't do in ES5—you're just doing it with less typing. So the answer is yes, to the extent that there are classes in ES2015, there are also classes in ES5.

Comment: BI know that it is possible to rebuild classes and emulate them. But are they really already part of the programming language? On the official EMCA website it says "ECMAScript does not use classes such as those in C++, Smalltalk, or Java.".

Comment: ECMA may be referring to Javascript classes being prototype-based rather than inheritance-based.

Comment: `class` is just syntactic sugar for a pattern that is common in ES5. It doesn't add any new semantics to the language, and defining a class with the `class` keyword is semantically identical to defining a class in ES5 by creating a prototype and then adding methods to that prototype and so on. Classes in ES5 and classes in ES2015 are the same, it just takes less typing to declare one in ES2015. JavaScript classes are different from Java classes, but so too are Java classes different from C++ classes or Smalltalk classes.

Comment: @Jordan, *so too are Java classes different from C++ classes.* Are you referring to generics vs. templates? Because otherwise Java classes are much more related to C++ classes than Javascript classes are.

Comment: No, I'm not referring to generics vs. templates specifically. There are a hundred subtle and unsubtle semantic differences between classes in Java and C++, as are there between Smalltalk and Ruby or any other two OOP-capable languages you can name—but nevertheless, they all have classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript/ECMAScript is a [prototype-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) programming language.

Wikipedia’s definition of this is:

> Prototype-based programming is a style of object-oriented programming in which behaviour reuse (known as inheritance) is performed via a process of cloning existing objects that serve as prototypes. This model can also be known as prototypal, prototype-oriented, classless, or instance-based programming.

Well, know it is your decision whether to call them *classes*.

But some people in the JS world call them classes and with ECMAScript 6 there will be a keyword to create such prototypes, called `class`. (Which implies that these prototypes should be called *class*.)

---

Since you are writing a paper, you could take a definition of class (there are a few out there), mention which you used and whether that is applicable in JavaScript. (If that somehow belongs to your work.)

Some definitions of *class* are also summarized in a great book by John C. Mitchell. (Mitchell, John: Concepts in Programming Languages. Cambridge University Press, 2003.)

On *classes* in Simula he writes: (p. 326)

> Class: A Simula class is a procedure that returns a pointer to its activation record. The body of a class may initialize the object it creates.

On *classes* in Smalltalk he writes: (p. 327)

> Class: A Smalltalk class defines class variables, class methods, and the instance methods that are shared by all objects of the class. At run time, the class data structure contains pointers to an instance variable temple, a method dictionary, and the superclass.

He also states that the concept of *classes* in Java and C++ is very similar to the concept in Smalltalk, which was a OO pioneer.

We can see that *class* can be defined differently, but both definitions above don’t seem to quite match JavaScript prototypes.

Comment: We're certainly not calling prototypes (the objects) *classes* :-)

Comment: @Bergi Well, I personally also don’t do, but I have heard many people talking about "JavaScript classes".

Comment: So should I call them classes or is it better to say that JavaScript ECMAS5 class-based? Is there a correct scientific term?

Comment: @JavaForAndroid Are you writing some kind of paper about JavaScript? If not just call them whatever you like (prototype or class). Actually prototypes in JS are so often manipulated that in the end you don’t have the instance of a *class* so I think using *class* is not completely correct.

Comment: @JavaForAndroid: No, JavaScript is *not* class-based. It's object-based.

Comment: @Bergi, *We're certainly not calling prototypes (the objects) classes :-)* Who's that *we* you're speaking about? ;)

Comment: I am writing some kind of paper. So I would like to use the exact term if there is one.

Comment: @Bergi, I'm sorry to learn I'm not a member of the "JS community". May I inquire where you have found a definite consensus against the use of "class" in JS?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I'm not saying that the js community doesn't use the term "class" (see my own answer above), I only meant that when saying "class" we don't refer to the prototype object. Most people mean the entireness of the constructor function, the prototype object, it's methods, the shared inheritance, and the usage with `new`. All what makes the implementation of the concept (and I admit there are multiple ways to implement the concept, so it's not always as clear)

Comment: @JavaForAndroid These *things* you instantiate are called prototypes. You can take a definition of *class* (there are a few out there), mention which you used and whether that is applicable in JavaScript. (If that somehow belongs to your work.)

Comment: Great answer. I will refer to concept of classes and how they are applicable in JavaScript. I think that it depends on the community how it is called. There are no class elements, but that does not imply that ECMAS5 does not support classes. Thank you so much.

Comment: You’re welcome.  I’ve actually expanded my answer with some quotes from one of my favorite books concerning that topic.

Comment: I found in some papers that these classes are called "pseudo-classes". Is that a good description for it? I have read your update. I will check out the literature.

Comment: @JavaForAndroid Yes and no. From the point of a Java or C++ programmer it is a "pseudo-class". From the point of a JavaScript programmer it is a class. If you are comparing JavaScript classes to Java or C++ classes, they are definitely "pseudo-classes". The classes can be modified, you can also modify the objects and even delete "methods".

Comment: I am a Java developer and so I have obviously a different point of view. I will explain it in the context and that should be the best solution. Thank you for your help. I think this is the best answer.

Comment: @idmean: I wouldn't say that mutability does make it a pseudo-class - after all, you can modify classes even in Java via reflection. It just doesn't bear the simplicity of the equivalent js syntax :-)

Comment: @Bergi That's a point. But from the point of a C++ developer that may seem very strange. And as you said it is not a "every day thing".

Answer (score 2):

"[*class*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class#Computing)" is a term for many things. The [classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)) you are looking for are a *concept*, and are certainly used in JavaScript. We implement the concept by reification, which is easily possible with JavaScripts powerful, object-oriented [prototype inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming). This model is quite different from the object model used in other programming languages, where classes are more a compiler artifact than concrete objects.

That the concept is implemented by means of generic language features allows for multiple slightly different implementations (some of which even don't rely on prototypes). So when the term "class" is used, we don't know how exactly it would look like. Only if we refer to a specific class with an implementation, it's clear what structure is meant (assuming your familiar with the kind of implementation).
There is however a quite standard pattern (implementation) with a constructor function that is invoked with `new` to create instances, and a prototype object that is used for sharing methods. The pattern also defines how to setup inheritance and subclassing.

You're right that there is no syntactical `class` structure in ES5 (though the keyword is reserved, and implemented in ES6 by the standard structure).

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain):

> Classes are syntax sugar over constructor functions

You can use this new construction in ES5 by using some compiler:

- [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/)
- [Traceur](https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html)
- [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html)
- [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)