# Has ECMAScript discontinued prototye-based programing syntax in its 6th edition?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm a huge fan of JavaScript's ECMAScript5 syntax, mainly because, in my opinion, it was what made it unique among other object-oriented programming languages following relatively traditional programming style and syntax.

Not sure if ECMAScript5 syntax is still supported in ECMAScript6, i.e. if it's backward compatible. But, is there any reason for substituting the syntax, especially *prototype-based*  approach to defining classes in JavaScript, (not to mention inheritance, etc.) into a more traditional one (as in most object-oriented programming languages)?

To exemplify the syntax change, as per ECMAScript5 you could define a person class as such in JavaScript:

```
// ES5 class definition of a Person
function Person (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

//adding methods or properties to the Person prototype
Person.prototype.walk = function(){
    console.log(this.name + ' is walking');
}
```

Same implementation above in ES6:

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    walk() {
        console.log(this.name + ' is walking.');
    }
}
```

*I'm asking this question, because I believe, for some programmers maybe shifting back to a traditional syntax proves to be problematic at first due to being too accustomed to an older style. So why are such drastic changes brought at first place?*

Any information is highly appreciated.

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say that the folks writing the ES6 spec are trying to make Javascript appeal to more "mainstream" programmers (i.e. trained on Java-like object-oriented principles).

Comment: @RobertHarvey, why on hold. Is this question too broad to answer?

Comment: You didn't read the close reason?

Comment: So what do you suggest, should I delete it?

Comment: This question could be about any syntactical change in ES6. If someone doesn't feel ready to use any of the new features, they shouldn't be using it.

Comment: "*Not sure if ECMAScript5 syntax is still supported in ECMAScript6*" - Yes, ES6 is *fully* backwards-compatible. "*is there any reason for substituting the syntax*" - because [we're already using classes everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31908169/1048572), so it made sense to provide a new syntactical construct for the very same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

> JavaScript classes are introduced in ECMAScript 6 and are syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax is **not** introducing a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript. JavaScript classes provide a much simpler and clearer syntax to create objects and deal with inheritance.